# How to properly analyze groups of cumulative dose-response curves in a 2x2 design?

Tags: anova, biostatistics, curve-fitting

We have data from following experiment: Animals were divided into 4 groups by combination of 2 factors (2x2 design). We then extracted 2 blood vessel rings from each animal (animal = biological replicate, ring = technical replicate) and obtained cumulative dose-response curve for each ring.

We know from previous experiments that dose-response curves should correspond to 3-parameter Hill equation. We would like to see, if there are any differences in each of the curve parameters across all factor combinations.

In many papers people just average responses at each concentration for each group of animals and then compare means using ANOVA, however I don't think this is correct and it also doesn't answer our question (about difference in curve parameters).

Some people suggested to fit model with 4 different curves (1 for each group of animals) and compare it to a global fit. However as I understand it, this approach will only tell me if all data can be described by single curve and would not answer my question about curve parameters and factor effects.

Others told me that aforementioned approach is not correct, because since data points come from cumulative dose-response curves, they are not independent and I should fit separate curves for each animal, calculate corresponding curve parameters and then compare averages of these parameters across factors using two-way ANOVA.

What is the correct way to analyze this type of experiment?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have a suggestion that might help decide. Visually inspect a single scatterplot of all data, where each factor combination is a different color. You can also make similar scatterplots of each modeling approach and see if any individual approach stands out. The visual analysis of data plotted in this way is often informative, and the plots can become supporting evidence for the final choice of analytical method.